# Centering and positioning elements on the same row

Tags: html, css, position, center

i have a question about centering and positioning elements behind one another. I have a block of text on the left and only one word in this case about, which should be centered and on the same line as the e-mail.

```css
nav {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<address>
  <a href="#">Some text</a>
  <br>
  hi(at)mail.com
</address>

<nav>
  <a href="#">about</a>
</nav>
```

I tried to float the address to the left, but then the nav isn't in the center anymore. Any ideas how to accomplish this? It has to be easy, but i just don't know how.

**Edit**

The nav should be centered for the entire viewport, my current answer would be to absolute position the nav and set left and right to 0. but i don't know if this would be the best way to do it.

what it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if it is the best way but it looks like what you want to do

```css
nav {
left:50%;
 text-align: center;
}
address{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<address>
  <a href="#">Some text</a>
  <br>
  hi(at)mail.com
</address>

<nav>
<br/>
  <a href="#">about</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Make sure to clear that afterwards, otherwise it will affect other elements.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the outcome isn't exactly centered, but i tried it again with position: absolute and left: 0 right: 0 i got the outcome i wanted.

Comment: @user3640832 in this case you need to consider when the viewport is smaller than both elements, they will overlap, you'd need to sort this with a media query, besides that, it's a valid solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `display:table-cell`.
This way we can vertically-align the content to the bottom of the container element.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <address>
    <a href="#">Some text</a>
    <br>
    hi(at)mail.com
  </address>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">about</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:(Edited to include 50% width on table-cell items)

```
.container{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
address, nav{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  width:50%;
}
```

View the codepen here: http://codepen.io/eoghanTadhg/pen/NNYgYg

Comment: `nav` isn't really at the center.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to show you this solution because it combines a couple of ideas that are sometimes considered problematic. Here I use the fact that by default inline-block elements vertically align by the last line of their content. That's just what you need. Also, it uses visible overflow of a block with zero width, to centre the nav contents horizontally within the containing block.

```css
nav {
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-0.25em;
}
address { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:0;
}
address > * { 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<address>
  <a href="#">Some text</a>
  <br>
  <span>hi(at)mail.com</span>
</address>

<nav>
  <a href="#">about</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: your answer works the best for me, i could have never come up with it myself, thanks. there is just one issue: it first didn't work because i had letter-spacing on the body tag. Do you think this solution is viable, because you are talking about promlematic ideas?

Comment: The solution isn't sensitive to letter-spacing, except you may have to adjust the margin-left setting, but post a new question if you do hit issues.